# How to keep integration test running to catch hangfire trigger?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, hangfire

`ASP.NET Core 2.2.0`

I'm working with `Hangfire` which schedules tasks on the same thread using a database.

How can I keep my integration-test running to allow `Hangfire` to trigger the callback ?

I want to catch a breakpoint placed in the callback method.

Comment: I'm wondering the same, in the past I used to just use a Thread sleep for a couple of seconds but that's far from optimal..

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same.

Best I could come up with after spending a couple of hours looking, was something like this

```
private bool HasJobsCompleted()
{
    if (_jobMonitoring == null)
    {
        _jobMonitoring = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
    }
    var stats = _jobMonitoring.GetStatistics();
    return stats.Scheduled == 0 && stats.Succeeded > 0;
}
```

Note; that I set `_jobMonitoring` here as `JobStorage.Current` is not set during the ctor call of my integration test.